# couldn't match type 'a' with 'String'

Tags: haskell

I'm doing sort of a compiler in haskell and I came up to this problem:

This is the code I have for the moment:

```haskell
data Command a = Input a | Print a

readCommand:: Read a => String -> Command a
readCommand entrada
    | tokens!!0 == "INPUT" = Input (tokens!!1)
    | tokens!!0 == "PRINT" = Print (tokens!!1)
    where
        tokens = words entrada
        listInstr = lines entrada
```

but I get this error:

> Couldn't match type 'a' with 'String';
> 'a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for readC:: Read a => String -> Command a
>
> Expected type: [a] ; Actual type: [String]

Does this error mean that if I declare on the function that I have a string, type 'a' cannot be a String too?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess you where looking for `...= Input (read $ tokens!!1)` ... which will try `read` the words/tokens from your input-string into your type `a`

Comment: BTW: maybe you should start with a parser which should handle different types of tokens (data-types) first?

Comment: PS it means that you promised to return a `a` but then only produced a `String` - so if I say `readCommand "INPUT 12" :: Command Int` you should see the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes i got many other data-types i just didnt want to post unnecessary info about my problem

Answer (score 4):

The error means that if you promise a `Command a` as the result, you must produce a result of type `Command a` that the caller of your function requests (as long as it meets the condition `Read a`). So your type signature allows the following code to compile:

```
x :: Integer
x = readCommand ""

y :: String
y = readCommand ""

z :: [Double]
z = readCommand ""
```

All of those uses of `readCommand` are valid according to your type signature, so `readCommand` needs to be able to produce values of any of those types. The way you defined it, it will always produce a `Command String`, no matter which type was requested. And since that's not what you promised in your type, you get a compilation error.

If you want to produce `Command String`s as your result, you need your type to be `readCommand :: String -> Command String`. If you want your type to be what it is now, you need to actually produce values of the requested type.

Note that you require `Read a`, but never actually use the `read` function, which would be the point of requiring `Read a`.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks for the help now I understand what was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: is there any way to make haskell infer the type of the string?

I mean, for this case is easy because i can simply change the data type and make it expect a String (since it will be variables anyway), but how would you do to make it generic? For instance: if tokens!!1 is 5, make haskell get 5 as an int and not an String

Comment: @Outer2g Just use `read`, which has the type `Read a => String -> a`.

Comment: Sorry about my insistence but, how do you use read? It compiles but, when i execute it with string : "INPUT X" : Input *** Exception: Prelude.read::no parse. I know that when using ghci and using read you have to cast it like so : read "X"::String, but I can't figure out how to use it in code. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Outer2g `read "X" :: String` isn't a cast, it just tells `read` which type you want when it's not clear from context. If you use it in a context where a String is needed, you don't need the type annotation. Anyway the problem isn't that GHC can't figure out the type (if it were, you'd get a compile error telling you so), it's that X is not a valid input for String. If you try `read "X" :: String` in GHCi, you'll see that you get the same exception. `String`'s `read` instance expects a Haskell-style string, double quotes included. So it'd need to be `INPUT "X"`, `INPUT X`. ...

Comment: @Outer2g ... If you want the syntax to be `INPUT X`, you can't use `read`. You'll have to create your own `Read`-style type class that reads values in your specific syntax.